# MYSQL Order by column shuffling same values

Tags: sorting, mysqli

I have a table in MySQL database, which looks like:

```
ID | Priority
A  | 3
B  | 2
C  | 2
D  | 2
E  | 1
```

I need to get the results from this table ordered by Descending 'Priority', but shuffled where 'Priority' value is the same.

So every time I make a query I would get the results like:

```
A, C, D, B, E
A, D, B, C, E
A, C, D, B, E
```

Is this possible with MySQLi query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may add an extra tier to the `ORDER BY` clause which does random ordering in the case of a tie of the priority:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    Priority DESC,
    RAND();

A, D, B, C, E
A, C, D, B, E
```

### Demo

Comment: wow, thank you didn't know you can use RAND() after specifying ORDER